# Writing image binary data uploaded back as image file in disk

Tags: image, rust

I'm doing a small project where I allow users to upload text along with an image from the front end (react). The text is processed and the image is written to disk on the server end. My web server backend is using rust Axum.

I can write it to disk no error but I can't view the image at all (web server is in my laptop for local development). When I double click to view the image, it would have an error that the file cannot be opened as it may be damaged. Can someone point out where I did wrong? Below is my code snippet. Thanks in advance!

```
let mut title_one = String::from("");
let mut title_two = String::from("");

while let Some(mut field) = multipart.next_field().await.unwrap() {
        let name = field.name().unwrap().to_string();
        let data = field.bytes().await.unwrap();

        match name.as_ref() {
            "title_one" => title_one = str::from_utf8(&data).unwrap().to_owned(),
            "title_two" => title_two = str::from_utf8(&data).unwrap().to_owned(),
            "my_image" => {
                let file_name = Path::new("test.png").file_name().unwrap();

                let full_path = Path::new("image_dir").join(file_name);
                tokio::fs::write(full_path, data).await.unwrap();
            }
    }
```

test.png would be written to the image_dir but it's not a valid png file. I can't view it. I have also tried image crate as below. However, it has errors in decode ''Failed to read image: Unsupported(UnsupportedError { format: Unknown, kind: Format(Unknown) })'. I'm not too sure why.

```
"my_image" => {
                 let reader = Reader::new(Cursor::new(data))
                    .with_guessed_format()
                    .expect("This will never fail using Cursor");

                let img = reader.decode().expect("Failed to read image");
                img.save("image_dir/test.png")
                    .unwrap();
```

My front end code to upload is

```
const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
const data = new FormData();
data.append("my_image", e.target.files[0] || "");
data.append("title_one", formData.get("title_one")?.toString().trim() || "");
data.append("title_two", formData.get("title_two")?.toString().trim() || "");

const endpoint = '/api/my_endpoint';
const payload = {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: new Headers({
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   }),
   body: data,
}
```

Comment: You should try uploading a text file so you know what it should look like.

Comment: Yeah, I tried uploading a text file and it works with fs::write. Not sure what's wrong with image

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your frontend code. You're casting `e.target` to a `HTMLFormElement` and then using the field `files` on `e.target`. But the `HTMLFormElement` object doesn't have a `files` field on it ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)). As such, it's likely that you are uploading the empty string `""` as the image data.

The error:

```
Failed to read image: Unsupported(UnsupportedError { format: Unknown, kind: Format(Unknown) })'
```

appears if you try to decode an empty file.

You probably meant to access the `files` field on an `HTMLInputElement`. The following example works as expected:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
    <input id="input" type="file">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    document.querySelector("#form").onsubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append("my_image", document.querySelector("#input").files[0] || "");
        data.append("title_one", formData.get("title_one")?.toString().trim() || "");
        data.append("title_two", formData.get("title_two")?.toString().trim() || "");

        const endpoint = '...';
        const payload = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            }),
            body: data,
        };

        fetch(endpoint, payload);
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can test your API endpoint using an API client such as Postman.

Comment: hmm.. the image data is not empty string. I did console log the multipart data in the front end and also print the data len in the backend, it does have data. The file being wrote also have a few hundred kb, just that it can't be view as a valid png file

Comment: @Ruster Then, as another user suggests, you may want to try saving the data in your backend as a `txt` file and uploading a text file and see what you get. It would also be helpful if you could include a link to the corrupted image file in your post.

Comment: txt file works fine with fs::write. here's the png file generated out

https://photos.onedrive.com/share/1464B1C4A0506C26!23768?cid=1464B1C4A0506C26&authkey=!AFwaN6PVeHesooE&ithint=photo&e=YbAYuj

note that since it's not valid, you can't view it, only can download it

Comment: @Ruster The image you provided contains many "unicode replacement characters" in its raw data (hexadecimal: `ef bf bd`). This can happen if the image data is stored in a unicode string at some point. Without further details on how your image is being uploaded, it's hard to say where the exact problem is.

Comment: I see, thanks for helping to check. I'm using react front end and upload as multipart-form data. I thought I might be missing on how I should write it back as image file. txt file works when I used fs::write, not sure should I use image crate to write it back as image file. Anyways, I try to dig further on my end to see what additional info I can provide